# How to get success when Instagram sharing completed in Android

Tags: android, instagram, instagram-api

I am trying to sharing images on my Instagram using my android app. but I am unable to get success when images sharing done. 
I used Intent process but in same I am unable to get success when image sharing completed.

```
 Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

// Limit this call to instagram
        share.setPackage("com.instagram.android");

// Set the MIME type
        share.setType("image/jpg");

// Create the URI from the media
        File media = new File("/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20170627_222256129_HDR.jpg");
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(media);

// Add the URI to the Intent.
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

        try {
            // Fire the Intent.
            startActivityForResult(share, REQUEST_CODE);
        } catch(ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            // instagram not installed
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some explanation about startActivityForResult.

When you start sharing you make an intent with different information then you start your activity with a special method and a requestCode (A unique Integer that you decide)

```
startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode)
```

Good practice is to have some static integer somewhere in a configuration file

then in onActivityResult you wait for a return from instagram:

```
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
switch (requestCode) {
    case INSTAGRAM_REQUEST_CODE:
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // Here you do what you have to do.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Already done that. When I post the image it will not return in the app.

Comment: Can you provide your onActivityResult? Just in case.

Comment: You can check thi   @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE:
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    // Here you do what you have to do.
                    System.out.println("Done Sharing...");
                }
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

you can use startActivityForResult() and maybe result is RESULT_OK

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent i){
}
```